# CXF client without servlet

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to use CXF (with WS-Security, SAML, SOAP) without a servlet container. I saw this [link about not using spring](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html#ServletTransport-UsingtheservlettransportwithoutSpring)
 but that solution still requires a container I think. I am using Vert.x and would like to keep that as my server.

Comment: From the title I assume that you just want to create a client? No servlet container is needed for that, just add a dependency and use it as described here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html

Comment: @DennisKieselhorst Yes that is what I was looking for. Post this is an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the title I assume that you just want to create a client? No servlet container is needed for that, just add a dependency and use it as described here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html